# How to skip invocation of super method from abstract class in junit test?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

What is the better way to write unit test for such case

```
public abstract class Parent {

     public void initialize() {
        //some logic
     }
}
public class Child extends Parent {
    public void initialize(){
        super.initialize()
        //some logic
    }
}

@Test
public void testInitialize() {
    Child child = new Child();

    // Prevent/stub logic in super.method()
    Mockito.doNothing().when(child)./*super method called*/

    verify(...)

}
```

The problem in mocking of super method from parent abstract class, I need to prevent execution of it.

I have found approach for non-abstract parent class, but it doesn't work in my case :

```
   Child spy = Mockito.spy(new Child());

    // Prevent/stub logic in super.method()
    Mockito.doNothing().when((Parent)spy).initialize();
```

Comment: What you want seems impossible, since the only way to invoke an overridden superclass method is from the subclass method. You can't do this from a mock / stub, and even your non-abstract solution does not work (it compiles, but it doesn't skip the subclass execution). Maybe we can help if you tell us _why_ / for what testing goal you need this execution prevention?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `Child extends Parent` is an implementation detail of `Child`, and your test shouldn't care about it. This is usually a signal that you need to restructure your base class, such as by introducing dependency injection.